# Dislaying certain attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, html

I am displaying all of the attributes right next to the product as shown below

[image]

I am doing it by adding

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional')?>
```

to my theme

> \app\design\frontend\ultimo\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

as explained [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/Show-product-attributes-on-magento-1-frontend/m-p/107454#M5392)

But this display all of the attributes. How can I display only specific ones on the top part?

Comment: Do you want to show specific attributes on both the sections or for the top one?

Comment: Only for the top one

Comment: Then you cannot call additional as additional will call all the attributes whose setting is show in product view page to yes.

Comment: Isn't there a way of getting the specific values from calling additional or does it have to be another way?

Comment: You need to call it different way.

Comment: Can you recommend a way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84177/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-konstantin-patroev).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code to your **local.xml** or any module's layout xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label"> 
    <reference name="product.info"> 
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.customattributes" as="customattributes" after="alert_urls" template="catalog/product/view/customattributes.phtml"/> 
    </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

Create **customattributes.phtml** under:

> app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view/customattributes.phtml

with below code:

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Your Title') ?></h2>
<table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
    <col width="25%" />
    <col />
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Custom Label') ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getCustomcode() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Custom Label1') ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getCustomcode1() ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Custom Label2') ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_product->getCustomcode2() ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You need to change the attribute codes and labels according to your requriement.

Comment: I got the value of the label with `$_product->getAttributeText("attribute_code");` 
but do you know how to get the label of the attribute

Comment: getAttributetext is working for dropdown attributes.

Comment: That is true, but when i try with `$_product->getData("attribute_code");` to a non dropdown attribute it gives me a value not mentioned in any of the store views

Comment: What value it returns?

Comment: For my attribute "Shipping Type" i have DHL as a value but it returns 4

Comment: Shipping type is dropdown attribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84186/discussion-between-konstantin-patroev-and-sukumar-gorai).

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of **additional** block with the different name and custom template file.

E.g.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.custom.attributes" template="catalog/product/view/custom_attributes.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
</block>
```

Now you can call this block in your phtml file as given below

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.custom.attributes')?>
```

Now copy content from the file

`app/design/frontend/base/default/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` to your **custom_attributes.phtml** file

Then you can unset the attributes from the array which you don't want to show

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/catalog/product/view/custom_attributes.phtml

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct()
?>
<?php if($_additional = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>
    <table class="data-table" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
        <col width="25%" />
        <col />
        <tbody>

        <?php 
            // unset your unwanted attributes from the array
            unset($_additional['your_attribute_code']);
        ?>

        <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
            <tr>
                <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table')</script>
<?php endif;?>
```